# Servlet not forwarding - Servlet exception

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

My servlet is not forwarding correctly. I keep getting forwarded to the Tomcat-8.5 404 or 500 error pages depending what I try. When I get the 500 error, it just says the servlet threw an exception.

I'm attempting to retrieve the name of an anchor tag (in a nav bar), and based on the name forward it to the correct JSP. Once I get this working I will use this servlet to check for existing sessions or start new ones.

Many thanks for your help.

Below is my servlet mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SessionTracker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SessionTracker</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<!-- Servlet Maps -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SessionTracker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/donate/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Below is the anchor tag:

`<li><a href="/donate/donate.jsp" name="donate">Donate</a></li>`

Note, I have also tried the following on the anchor tag:

`<li><a href="/donate/donate.jsp?name=donate" name="donate">Donate</a</li>`

Below are the respective Java functions:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
    String url = forwardRequest(request, response, sc);

    sc.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}

private static String forwardRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ServletContext sc){
    String url = new String("");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    switch(name){ //switch state to determine which
        case "donate":
            url = "/donate/donate.jsp";
            break;

        case "mission":
            url = "/about/missionStatement.jsp";
            break;
    }

    return url;
}
```

Comment: what is that exception?

Comment: When I was able to pull the stack trace from the log, I got a NullPointerException and another time I got a StackOverflow.

Comment: The log was also still giving loads of output even after I stopped Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Ok Let's analyze your code:

1.- dd (web.xml)

```
<servlet-class>SessionTracker</servlet-class>
```

Try not to use Default package, (Although there is no problem here)

```
<url-pattern>/donate/*</url-pattern>
```

Oh Boy, here is a problem, you're saying to the Container, HEY, If someone uses the url http://localhost:8080/mysite/donate/whateverIDon'tCare call the Servlet SessionTracker, so I can use this diferents paths and it will call the same Servlet

```
/mysite/donate/some
/mysite/donate/hereWeGo
/mysite/donate/lol
```

So that is not good, try to change it to

```
<url-pattern>/donate/SesionTrackerServlet</url-pattern>
```

2.- Look at your

```
<li><a href="/donate/donate.jsp?name=donate" name="donate">Donate</a</li>
```

can you see the failure? yes as I said , when a user click here it will call your Servlet, so your servlet will call your method forwardRequest and What do you think will happen? yes it will foward to  url = "/donate/donate.jsp"; but wait, did you see my point 1? your  will call again the servlet and again the method and again and again and again and booooom....Estado HTTP 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception because you made a Loop.

BUT AS I SAID CHANGE THAT TO THIS:

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>SessionTracker</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>SessionTracker</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>SessionTracker</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/donate/SessionTrackerServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now enter this url (of course change your port if you need)

http://localhost:8080/Test/donate/SessionTrackerServlet?name=donate

And woooala =)

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hhTO.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqha7.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUvn4.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tge2x.png
```

Comment: no problem ;) Sorry for the images, i couldn't post it good :( I'm learning