# How can I link my HTML page to Java Servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I want to build a web application in  java,but can't find a way to link my html to java

Comment: what did you mean with **but can't find a way to link my html to java** ?

Comment: What is the linking statement for servlets?

Comment: I guess this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882198/servlet-not-forwarding-servlet-exception/42883047#42883047

Comment: Perhaps it would be good if you read some documentation on how a Servlet Web Application works, e.g. start with a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=servlet+101)

Answer (score 0):

You can put form to your html page and give them serlet url pattern as follow :

```
<form action="/servlet_url_pattren">
...
</form>
```

Server side web.xml

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>path_to_servlet_class</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet_url_pattern</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```